# actionscript3 get random element from json array

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, json

How to import json file in action script and then get random element from json array/object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using as3corelib for parsing JSON. You can download it here:
https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

I wrapped it to class:

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class JSONLoader extends EventDispatcher 
{

    private var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader() ;
    private var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    public var jsonDecoded:Object = new Object();

    public function JSONLoader(DataURL:String):void
    {

        var JSONString:String = DataURL;
        //trace("JSONLoader - JSONString = "+JSONString);

        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(JSONString);

        //var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSON);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, urlLoadErrorHandler);
        loader.load(urlRequest);

        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSON) ;

    }

    public function decodeJSON(event:Event):void
    {               
        trace("JSONLoader - Jason - "+event.target.data);

        jsonDecoded = JSON.decode(event.target.data);       
        dispatchEvent (new Event("dataReady"));     

        removeListeners();
    }

    public function urlLoadErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        trace("Jason - unable to load data");
        dispatchEvent (new Event("dataFailed"));
        removeListeners();
    }

    public function removeListeners():void
    {
        loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSON) ;
        loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, urlLoadErrorHandler);         
    }

    public function returnJsonDecoded():Object
    {
        trace("Jason jsonDecoded - "+jsonDecoded);
        return jsonDecoded;
    }   

}
```

Then call it like this:

```
public function getData():void{
        var _URLpath:String = "localdata.json";
        jsonLoader = new JSONLoader(_URLpath);
        jsonLoader.addEventListener("dataReady", collectJSONData);
        jsonLoader.addEventListener("dataFailed", doJSONFailed);
    }
private function collectJSONData(evt:Event):void
    {
        jsonObject = jsonLoader.returnJsonDecoded();
}
```

Then you have **jsonObject** and you can use like array and randomly pick up items.

Comment: just extend `EventDispatcher` as there's absolutly no reason this should extend `Sprite`

Answer (score 4):

Download [AS3CoreLib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) by Mike Chambers and use the included [JSONDecoder](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/serialization/json/JSONDecoder.as) class to convert the JSON string into an ActionScript object (an array in your case).

```
var myArray:Array = new JSONDecoder(myJsonArray, true).getValue();
```

If it's a JSON object with an array in it, you'll have to write something like this:

```
var myObject:* = new JSONDecoder(myJsonObject, true).getValue();
var myArray:Array = myObject.theArray;
```

Then generate a random nr between 0 and the last index in the array:

```
var randomIndex:int = Math.round(Math.random() * (myArray.length - 1));
```

and access the element:

```
var myElement:* = myArray[randomIndex];
```

Comment: Just like any other file. The answer of @Benny7500 explains how to load it from a server.

Comment: I have this error: "Call to a possibly undefined method JSONDecoder."

Comment: Did you put the AS3CoreLib library in your build path? Did you include the import statement: `import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSONDecoder;`